# javascript in Internet Explorer 10, no respond

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

Could you tell me why this js is working in Firefox and Chrome, but is not working in Internet Explorer? I am trying to solve that 3 days now, and I have no idea why it is not working. I would like this to be working at least on IE 8,9 and 10. I will be really happy if anyone would now how to fix this.

**SCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('<img class="envtop" src="images/envtop.jpg" alt=" "/>').prependTo('#testimo li');
$('<img class="envbot" src="images/envbot.png" alt=" "/>').appendTo('#testimo li');
$('<img class="envshadow" src="images/shadow.png" alt=" "/>').appendTo('#testimo li');

$('.envelope').mouseover(function() {
   $(this).find('.envtop').addClass('envani') 
     .end().find('.envbot').addClass('envani') 
     .end().find('.list').addClass('listani');
});

$(".envelope").mouseout(function() {
     $(this).find('.envtop').removeClass('envani')
    .end().find('.envbot').removeClass('envani')
    .end().find('.list').removeClass('listani');
});

$('.envelope').click(function() {
    $(this).find('.list')
    .toggleClass("listmove");
});

});
```

**HTML**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head>
<link href="style2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.custom.33897.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/js1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="testimo">
<li class="envelope">
<div class="list">
 <blockquote>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXX</blockquote>
 </div>
</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
      .envelope {
      width:300px;
      height:150px;
      position:relative;
      padding: 120px 24px 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      float: left;
      -webkit-transition:1s;
      transition:1s;
      cursor: pointer;
      }
      .list {
      width:236px;
      height:180px;
      background:white;
      padding: 30px 20px 0;
      font-size: 16px;
      -webkit-transition:1s;
      position:absolute;
      top:120px;
      left:36px;
      z-index:2;
      -webkit-transition:0.8s;
      transition:0.8s;
      font-size: 16px;
      background:gray;
      }
      .envtop {
      position:absolute;
      top:20px;
      left: 24px;
      z-index:1;
      -webkit-transition:0.5s;
      transition:0.5s;
      }
      .envbot {
      position:absolute;
      top:20px;
      left: 24px;
      z-index:3;
      -webkit-transition:0.5s;
      transition:0.5s;
      }
      .envani {
      -ms-transform:rotate(6deg);
      -webkit-transform:rotate(6deg);
      transform:rotate(6deg);
      left: 35px;
      top: 10px;
      }
      .listani {
      top:80px;
      left: 45px;
      }
      .envshadow {
      position: absolute;
      bottom:0;
      z-index: 4;
      left: 0;
      }
      .listmove {
      top:0px;
      }
```

Comment: Can you describe what it is supposed to do and / or put this in a jsfiddle for ease

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check the given below jsfiddle link in IE10

[LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/smanimani/vMSh9/1/)

Note : Where you wrote your js code?. Is it external js?. If it is internal(page itself) js you need to write javascript within `<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> ... </javascript>` tag.

Comment: You don't need to do anything of the sort. Javascript can be included anywhere on the page either in a script tag or from an external url.

Comment: Thanks, could you tell me why I can not use js file?

Comment: You can use external JS file., not an issue., Can you check this link in IE?

Comment: Try with `Developer Tools (F12)` in IE., You can easily find what errors occured..,,